# JS: Why `message` property of `Error` is non-enumerable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

According to [ES2017 spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-error-objects) the `message` property of `Error` is non-enumerable. I'm wondering why so?
With non-enumerable property `message` it's impossible for example to spread the `Error` object like

```
const payload = new Error('oops!');    

// Few lines after

const nextState = {
   ...payload
};
```

This especially useful when working with Redux and SFA(Standard Flux Actions).
SFA allows the payload of an action to be an `Error` object.
Such action can be processed by a reducer like

```
// e.g. with redux-actions library
// that provides `handleActions` helper

export default handleActions({  
   [ERROR_ACTION]: (state, ({ payload }) => ({ ...state, ...payload })
}, initialState)
```

But because of `message` property of `Error` is non-enumerable the payload from the code above won't be spreaded.

Has anyone a good answer for this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place for questions about language design decisions. You are probably better off asking on https://esdiscuss.org/ .

Comment: If the state is just an error object, why not just set that as the state directly? Object Spread is for merging objects, merging multiple instances of a class rarely makes sense...

Comment: **Felix Kling**, thank you fro the link!

**loganfsmyth**, yeah, I know. This is a simplified example not fully covering the problem.

Comment: See also [Why don't these error properties show under keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71070767/1048572) and [Why the message and stack properties of an error object are not enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56646649/1048572)