# Why don't these error properties show under keys?

Tags: javascript

It seems from [Object.getOwnPropertyNames vs Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658488/object-getownpropertynames-vs-object-keys), that the main difference between [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) is that the former only returns some of the properties -- those that are enumerable. So I'm wondering for something like an `Error` object, why it's decided that the properties aren't enumerable. For example:

```js
try {
    let field="XYZ";
    field.a.b.c;
} catch (error) {
    console.log('111', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error));
    console.log('222', Object.keys(error));
}
```

Why for example does the Error object not make those properties enumerable? When is a property usually made enumerable?

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984533/what-are-the-benefits-of-making-properties-non-enumerable

Comment: this might help [Developer.Mozilla.Org Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: See also [Why `message` property of `Error` is non-enumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42283600/1048572) and [Why the message and stack properties of an error object are not enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56646649/1048572)