# spread operator is not working for the error object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add new property to the error object. but i dont want create new error class for it.

but, when trying to add to the error object, the spread on error is not working.

```js
let error = new Error("new error message")
console.log({...error, foo : "bar"})
```

This is just printing `{foo : "bar"}`

why the spread operator is not working?

Comment: `error` is not iterable.

Comment: See [Why `message` property of `Error` is non-enumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42283600/1048572), [Why don't these error properties show under keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71070767/1048572) and [Why the message and stack properties of an error object are not enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56646649/1048572)

Comment: @mplungjan But you don't want descriptors, you want the property values

Comment: @jarmod doesn't matter, this is object spread, it doesn't use iterators. It takes own enumerable properties.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, you're right: enumerable rather than iterable (although error is also not iterable).